# RESOLVED - Spring Boot Starter Mail - failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb

I want to share the solution for above issue when using Spring Boot Starter Mail and attempt to create instance of MimeMessageHelper results in exception:
failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap

The issue is behind the jaxb-core dependency in version 4.0.0 which brings angus-activation library dependency. The library if loaded first doesn't have a public class of LogSupport.
The correct source of LogSupport is from com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation library.

Solution is to exclude the following in jaxb-core dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.0</version>
 <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
   <artifactId>angus-activation</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

At the same time the following dependency should be available:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
 <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just want to share sample for gradle/kotlin

`configurations.all {
    exclude(group = "org.eclipse.angus", module ="angus-activation")
}`

Comment: this worked for me.  OP's solution is the answer

Comment: I believe this is a bug in `org.eclipse.angus`, which should be superseding the legacy `com.sun.activation`version. I reported the issue here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-activation/issues/26

Comment: I got the error after updating some docx4j libraries to v11.4.9, and it worked form as well.

Comment: `I want to share the solution for above issue` please format your post as a question, AND an answer (and then accept the answer). Not one unanswered question that includes 'the answer'. If for no other reason, the benefit for you is you get reputation/votes for both things :).

Comment: Same issue after migration to spring boot 3, also removed angus-activation and it resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the culprit dependency (angus-activation). Anyway, I wouldn't include specifically any `com.sun.*` package, since it is not allowed since Java11. For me, excluding angus-activation from the Maven reactor was enough.

Answer (score 1):

For me helped adding that dependencies to pom.xml :)

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, It saved me a lot of time