# SpringBootStarterMail-IllegalAccessError:failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I am implementing a service for sending emails. My company provided me only the SMTP host. When I am trying to send the MimeMessage I am facing an exception:

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap (com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport and javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Gradle implementations:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
implementation 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.0'
implementation 'org.hudsonci.libs:hudson-jaxb:2.2.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
```

Code:

```
  @Async
  @SneakyThrows
  public void sendMail(MailDTO mailDTO) {
    log.info("Sending mail to {}", mailDTO.to());
    MimeMessage message= new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties()));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailDTO.to()));
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@test.com"));
    message.setSubject(mailDTO.subject());
    message.setContent(mailDTO.content(), "text/plain");
    Transport.send(message);
    log.info("Email sent to {}", mailDTO.to());
  }
```

In application.properties I am able to have only **mail.smtp.host**.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034101/resolved-spring-boot-starter-mail-failed-to-access-class-com-sun-activation

Comment: Your XML dependencies aren't compatible remove those as well as the activation one. That being said, instead of manually sending a mail use the Spring `JavaMailSender` and put the configuration in your application.properties.